# how to have google form data emailed with bold text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently using the following script to have google spreadsheet email my google form responses to me.  All the text in the email is plain text, but I would like the headers to be bold text.  I have tried several variations of adding the java command for bold text into the code to accomplish this but I am basically guessing since I have zero code writing experience.  Is it possible and how should my script look to succeed?  Thank you.

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
    var emailSubject    = "MOD Report";  

    // Set with your email address or a comma-separated list of email addresses.
    var yourEmail       = "xxxx@xxxx.com";

    // Set with your spreadsheet's key, found in the URL when viewing your spreadsheet.
    var docKey          = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";

    // If you want the script to auto send to all of the spreadsheet's editors, set this value as 1.
    // Otherwise set to 0 and it will send to the yourEmail values.
    var useEditors      = 0;

    // Have you added columns that are not being used in your form? If so, set this value to 
    // the NUMBER of the last column that is used in your form.
    // for example, Column C is the number 3
    var extraColumns    = 0;

    if (useEditors) {
        var editors = DocsList.getFileById(docKey).getEditors();
        if (editors) { 
            var notify = editors.join(',');
        } else var notify = yourEmail;
    } else {
        var notify = yourEmail;
    }

    // The variable e holds all the submission values in an array.
    // Loop through the array and append values to the body.

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("FormResponses1");
    if (extraColumns){
        var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,extraColumns).getValues()[0];
    } else var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    var message = "";
    for(var i in headers) {
        message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.values[i].toString() + '\n\n'; 
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(notify, emailSubject, message); 
}
```

Comment: I think the email clients show text surrounded by `*` and `*` rendered as bold. You might try that for headers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **htmlBody** advanced parameter.

[Google Documentation - Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

### Here is some example code:

Note:  the HTML bold tags:  `<b>text here</b>`

```
function sendEmail() {

  var message = "This is <b>the</b> message";

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "theEmail@example.com",
    subject: "This is the subject line",
    htmlBody: "<br>" +
              "inline text" +
              message,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this snippet:

```
for(var i in headers) {
    message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.values[i].toString() + '\n\n'; 
}

MailApp.sendEmail(notify, emailSubject, message);
```

with this:

```
for(var i in headers) {
    message += "<b>" + headers[i] + '</b> = '+ e.values[i].toString() + '<br>'; 
}

MailApp.sendEmail(notify, emailSubject, "", {htmlBody:message});
```

Comment: This is very close to a solution, however, instead of making the headers bold, it made all the form responses bold while leaving the headers plain text.